# How can I put mongoose queries like (find, findOneAndUpdate) in a function on a different file than my route?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

how can I put mongoose queries like (find, findOneAndUpdate) in a function on a different file than my route? I want to reuse these queries in multiple places in my project.
Here is my simple project:
project/
    helpers/
       helper.js
    models/
       customer.model.js
     app.js

My initial app.js file looks like this.

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

let Customer = require("./models/customer.model");
let helper = require("./helpers/helper");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/rest-api-workshop", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
});

app.use("/test",(req, res)=> {
    Customer.find({}, "-_id")
    .then(doc => {
        return res.json(doc);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return res.status(500).json(err);
    })
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.info(`Server has started on ${PORT}`));
```

my customer.model.js file looks like this:
    let mongoose = require("mongoose");

```
let CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    }

}, { collection: 'myCustomers' });

module.exports = mongoose.model("Customer", CustomerSchema);
```

Using just these two files all works well when I run http://localhost:3000/test I get the results from myCustomers collection.

When I try to put the find query in a function on another file, I do not return anything when I run http://localhost:3000/test. Under this approach here is my new app.js file:

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

let Customer = require("./models/customer.model");
let helper = require("./helpers/helper");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/rest-api-workshop", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
});

app.use("/test",(req, res)=> {
    var x = helper.runQuery();
    return res.json(x);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.info(`Server has started on ${PORT}`));
```

my helper.js file looks like.

```
module.exports = {
    runQuery: function () {
        let Customer = require("../models/customer.model");
        Customer.find({}, "-_id")
            .then(doc => {
                return doc;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return "invalid";
            })
    }
}
```

Why does the second approach not work? I believe it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of node js, but do not know how to solve this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your **helper.js** do something like this

```
 const Model = require('path to model');
    exports.runQuery = (req, res) => {
      Model.find()
        .then(data => {
          // do something here 
        })
        .catch(err => {
          // handle here
        });
    };
```

then in **app.js**

```
const bla = require('path to helper');

app.get('/test', bla.runQuery);
```